# Dynamic Trigger Function

Tags: c++, eventhandler

I am currently trying since several hours to make a completely dynamic EventHandler. But, whatever I try seems to not work.

Here is a quick diagram of what the EventHandler should do:

```
EventHandler<EventName>::Add (void* listener);

EventHandler<EventName>::Trigger(...);
```

Every Event that gets added by the `Add` method, gets safed in a local std::vector. So far so good, until this, everything is fine and pretty clear. We create a template and the simple trigger function.

However, now comes the issue, the `Trigger` function.  To give a better understanding, this EventHandler triggers functions from Native C++ Code to CLI Code.

To trigger the CLI function, I need:

- void* address (OK)
- arguments (not OK)

Inside the Trigger() function, I'd like to have to such code:

```
//WndProc Example Event
reinterpret_cast<void(__stdcall *)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)>(clrVoidPtr)(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

However... this is not dynamic (because the args are defined inside). I want to call it with the arguments from the actual `Trigger (...)` method. I know I have to work with `va_args` and similar, but even that, it seems impossible to me to make an actual Proof of Concept out of this?

Is it even possible to have a completely dynamic EventHandler, where the Trigger function accepts every argument and simply calls the appropriate function with it?

Right now my solution is to create a Event Class for each Event that I have and define the actual parameters in the Trigger function, as example:

```
void WndProcEvent::Trigger(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

... but since I will have a lot of events, this is not acceptable to me even if I create them by using macros (which are horrible to debug btw...)

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggesting creating a simple object for each event type that defines the associated custom event signature and contains code for mapping from generic '(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)' format to custom signature. e.g:

```
// incomplete!

typedef void(WindowsCall *)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

struct OnClickEvent
{
public:
    typedef void (CustomCall *)(HWND, int x, int y);

    static void Invoke(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam, CustomCall customCall)
    {
         // invoke custom call here!
         ...
    }
};

template<string EventName, typename Invoker>
class EventHandler
{
    typedef std::vector<Invoker::CustomCall> Listeners;

    Listeners m_Listeners;

    void Add(Invoker::CustomCall customCall)
    {
        m_Listeners.Add(customCall);
    }

    void Trigger(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
    {
        for (Listeners::iterator it = m_Listeners.begin();
             it != m_Listeners.end();
             ++it)
             Invoker::invoke(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam, (*it));
    }

    // etc
    ...
};

// e.g Use
EventHandler<"OnClick", OnClickEvent> onClickHandler;
```

I actually did a similar thing for a project eons ago but used 'sigc++'
as I was not satisfied with using MFC/ATL (yuck!). Thats mainly because it was a macro soup!.

Hope that helps.